# Directory file search multiple images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using:

```
 String[] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Path, partNumber + ".jpg");
```

in order to get image files from a directory. The images are named after a partNumber and use an underscore character and a number to discern them apart. 
For example, a part may have 3 images: 10-100.jpg, 10-100_1.jpg, 10-100_2.jpg
How can I modify my code to get all 3 images for partNumber 10-100?

Comment: _Directory.GetFiles(Path, partNumber + "*.jpg");_ Just read the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184429/directory-file-search-multiple-images#59184429) about what you can write for _searchPattern_

Comment: However I don't undestand why you haven't followed the comments given to you in your previuos question. This one is a pretty duplicate of the previous one

Comment: Steve, I have tried that, but it is not ideal. Some partNumbers are like 10-100-1 with an image of 10-100-1.jpg. Using the wildcard includes the 10-100-1.jpg as well.

Comment: If the symbol - should always be the last one before the variable part then "-*.jpg". Perhaps you need to give some example of what is expected to return and what not.

Comment: Steve, I have tried both suggestions and neither work correctly. For my scenario these images should be found using a part number of 10-100: 10-100.jpg, 10-100_1.jpg, 10-100_2.jpg  This image should not be returned: 10-100-1.jpg Oh, also sorry about the duplicate question.

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path, partNumber + "*.jpg").Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s), "^" + Regex.Escape(partNumber) + @"(_\d+)?$")).ToList();`

Comment: Ulugbek, I was going to just do two searches which I got to work, then I tried your code. Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can solve using 2 ways.

Either scan folder twice with 2 different masks: `<partNumber>.jpg` and `<partNumber>_*.jpg`.

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string partNumber)
{
    return Enumerable.Concat(
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, partNumber + ".jpg"),
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, partNumber + "_*.jpg"));
}
```

Either scan folder once with regex filtering:

```
static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string partNumber)
{
    string fileNameGenericMask = partNumber + "*.jpg";
    string fileNameRegexPattern = "^" + Regex.Escape(partNumber) + @"(_\d+)?$";
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, fileNameGenericMask)
                    .Where(filePath => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath), fileNameRegexPattern));
}
```